# How to unpack received data in "big endian" into record?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a record

```
type
  Treply = record
    c: integer;
    b: integer;
    a: int64;
  end;
```

I receive data from server using UDP protocol, the data is in "big endian"

```
udp : TIdUDPClient;
received_data : TIdBytes;

udp.ReceiveBuffer(received_data);
```

How to decode received_data into normal int/int/int64 and put it into record Treply ?

Thanks

Comment: @Remy What are the recommended ways to make sure that GStack has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since the record will have no padding, you can simply copy the contents of the buffer onto your record.

```
var
  Reply: TReply;
....
Move(received_data[0], Reply, SizeOf(Reply));
```

And then you need to convert from network byte order to host byte order. And you know how to do that from your previous question.

To make sure that you don't ever get caught out by record padding/alignment issues you would be advised to pack any records that you blit onto the wire:

```
TReply = packed record
  ....
```

You also ought to check that `received_data` contains the right amount of information before calling `Move`.

Personally I would probably build your record into something a little more powerful, making use of Indy's functions to convert between host and network byte order.

```
type
  TReply = packed record
    c: integer;
    b: integer;
    a: int64;
    function HostToNetwork: TReply;
    function NetworkToHost: TReply;
  end;

function TReply.HostToNetwork: TReply;
begin
  Result.c := GStack.HostToNetwork(Cardinal(c));
  Result.b := GStack.HostToNetwork(Cardinal(b));      
  Result.a := GStack.HostToNetwork(a);
end;

function TReply.NetworkToHost: TReply;
begin
  Result.c := GStack.NetworkToHost(Cardinal(c));
  Result.b := GStack.NetworkToHost(Cardinal(b));      
  Result.a := GStack.NetworkToHost(a);
end;
```

Put it all together and your de-serializing code looks like this:

```
if Length(received_data)<>SizeOf(Reply) then
  raise SomeException.Create('...');
Move(received_data[0], Reply, SizeOf(Reply));
Reply := Reply.NetworkToHost;
```

Comment: Well, it has the same effect if executed on a little endian machine. But logically it's not the same thing. It's what you want, in my opinion. You don't want `ReverseBytes`. You want `NetworkToHost`, or in the last question it was `HostToNetwork`. Although they all have the same effect on a little endian machine, using `NetworkToHost`/`HostToNetwork` will lead to you code being more readable and clear. And I don't see why you need to bring in `ReverseBytes` from FireMonkey. You are using Indy. So use the Indy native tools for host/network byte order.

Comment: ok thanks, and how to use HostToNetwork instead ReverseBytes(@BEPacket.a, SizeOf(BEPacket.a)); ? i got a error when trying to do it like this packet := packet.HostToNetwork;

Comment: im getting "access vailation error.." when packet.a:=123; packet.b:=55; packet.c:=321; packet := packet.HostToNetwork; indy bug ?

Comment: That's because you haven't created any Indy components and so `GStack` has not been created. You need a call to TIdStack.IncUsage so that `GStack` will be created. That happens when you create an Indy component. If you don't do that anywhere, then you'll need to call TIdStack.IncUsage somewhere. For example in an initialization section. And then call `TIdStack.DecUsage` when you are done.

Comment: like that? initialization
  TIdStack.IncUsage;
finalization
  TIdStack.DecUsage; now all works, thanks)